Distance sensor types with sample rates >= 1 kHz and certain characteristics
I made a project a while ago, it was about making a device that can measure the time it takes for an athlete to run between two points. It consisted of two stations, both of which were based on ESP32-C3 microcontrollers. The stations connected to each other via Bluetooth, and they way they could detect an athlete passing in front of the station was using the HC-SR04-P ultrasonic distance measuring sensor.
Now, it works, but the sampling rate is 50 Hz (I couldn't get it to go lower than 20 ms per measurement, I know that is it's limit because of the way it works). That means that the maximum error per measurement is about 40 ms (each station could theoretically make a mistake of up to 20 ms).
I was wondering if there are any sensors that work on a similar principle, meaning that I don't need to have a retroreflective material on the opposite side of the sensor to be able to sense someone passing in front of it, or opposite facing emitter and detector, but enable me to have higher sampling frequencies, about a kilohertz would be pretty nice? This condition really simplifies the use of said device and I don't want to compromise on that.

I've changed your title slightly to make clear you're asking about types of sensors, and not product recommendations; since asking for which products to buy is off-topic here.

A HCSR04 module seems inappropriate for this intended use because its repetition rate is too slow (OP claims about 40ms).
However, its 40 kHz transmitter and receiver piezo elements should be able to detect a passing person, operating in continuous mode rather than its original radar-like pulse mode.
Since the intended application involves detecting a moving person, the transmitting sensor might be modified to emit a continuous 40 kHz signal.

As a person passes, a 40 kHz signal will reflect 40 kHz back to the receiving sensor. The amplitude of this reflecting signal should peak when the person walks (or runs) directly opposite the two sensors.
However, an aspect of the reflected signal that is more interesting is the frequency of reflected signal, caused by Doppler shift:

As the person approaches the transmitter/receiver pair, the receiver's detected frequency will be higher than the 40kHz transmitted.
As the person passes the transmitter/receiver pair, the receiver's detected frequency will be the same as 40 kHz transmitted.
As the person moves past the transmitter/receiver pair, the receiver's detected frequency will be lower than the 40 kHz transmitted.

Comparing transmitted frequency with received frequency requires a phase detector, which could be as simple as a digital exclusive-or gate. Another appropriate chip is CD4046, that includes oscillator, and phase detector.
Additional signal processing might also estimate the speed of a passing person.

Interesting, I didn't know it could be used in continuous mode. The thing is, I just need a simple "person moving in front of the sensor" detector and have it detect the person when it's just right in front of the sensor, not 10 cm behind or in front ( when looking from the perspective of the person running next ot it ). That's why I'm looking for a distance measuring sensor with narrow FoV, sampling rate at 1 KHz at least to be able to measure with milisecond precision, and to have it be relatively cheap is a nice plus.

A diffuse photoelectric sensor may be suitable for your purposes. They are commonly used in industry and a web search should give you plenty of training material. They have the transmitter and sensor in the same housing and work by detecting the diffuse reflection from objects in the field of view. Most will feature a background suppression setting or autotune.
I suspect that you'll need a laser type for the ranges you'll be interested in.
Here's a tutorial on a short range type: Datalogic on YouTube.

Ultrasonic sensors, radars, optical time of flight sensors… basically all sensors can work at the (relatively low!) rate of 1000 readings per second. Sure, for ultrasonic sensors you might want to code the pulses so that you don't have multiple "in flight" at once that you can't tell apart, but that's an implementation detail.
You just picked one sensor module that has very limited signalling rate.
